# Whirlpool gas dryer diagnostics

Tags: repair, dryer, appliances, laundry

My Whirlpool gas dryer stopped working efficiently recently. Peering into the burner hole shows clearly that it is sparking when the dryer starts, but doesn't seem to reignite later on. I checked the thermostats, solenoids, and fuses in the front and back with an ohm meter and they are all closed. I also cleaned out the vent pipe, and the blower as well. Still not working well.

Does anyone have a recommendation for next steps?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Some clarity would help (e.g. does it reliably ignite when cold, but doesn't reignite when hot?).

Comment: Yes. When "hot", the area glows orange but does not ignite. My current theory is the ignitor is bad. That is, It heats up but does not provide a spark. How is that spark manifested? You cannot light natural gas through heat alone, right?

Comment: Actually you can; a hot enough coil, and an air-gas mixture will ignite. Is the gas valve opening, or is the igniter just heating up?

Comment: I don't know. I don't smell gas though at the little porthole. I hear the solenoids click. Is there another way to tell?  Is a high temp how these ignitors work though?

Comment: I'm no pro, but I'll guess that the gas valve isn't opening when it's hot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ignitor and that resolved the issue.

I took it out, and the side of the ignitor facing the gas was dull,. The other side sparkled, like the new one I got. I wonder if I could have just flipped it over exposing the sparkled side to the gas -- the design was symmetrical. I considered it, but had already purchased the replacement.